# Sparse6 format broken for multigraphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

There seems to be a bug in `Export` for the "Sparse6" graph format, when the graph to be exported is a multigraph (*i.e.* has repeated edges). For example, take

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}];
```

Then

```
ExportString[g, "Sparse6"]
(*">>sparse6<<:Ab~"*)
```

which only looks OK, because it cannot be imported back

```
ImportString[%, "Sparse6"]
(*$Failed*)
```

Notice that the bug is within `Export` and not `Import`, because the output produced by Mathematica is also not accepted by nauty programs (created by the same guy who defined the "Sparse6" format in the first place).

Any idea how one could access Mathematica's implementation of `Export`, to maybe correct this bug? The "Sparse6" format itself is simple enough for me to try to write a crude exporter myself (I realize I can just avoid using `Export`, but I'd like to make this as transparent a fix as possible)

Comment: I have a Sparse6 importer in my IGraph/M package and I would be happy to take a contribution for an exporter.

Comment: I don't have time to look into this now, but I'll note that my importer handles this fine. `IGImportString[">>sparse6<<:Ab~", "Nauty"]`. You can use IGraph/M to import it. Are you sure the representation is incorrect? Can you give an example where the nauty suite does not accept this yet it is expected to handle multigraphs? Link to format spec is here: https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html

Comment: I looked carefully at this representation, and I cannot tell what would be wrong with it, although I can see that `listg -e` does not produce the output we would expect. The first character, `A`, represents the number of vertices, `ToCharacterCode["A"] - 63 == 2`. This is fine. Then the sequence of `b` and `x` values is `b=1, x=0, b=0, x=1` followed by all `1`s. This induces the edge list (1,0) (1,0) which is correct.

Comment: What seems to be incorrect is the padding, i.e. the `~` character at the end. This seems to be unnecessary, but I don't quite see why it would be harmful. If you have further doubts about the correctness, I suggest writing to the nauty mailing list and asking Brendan.

Comment: Regarding the use of the [tag:bugs] tag, please do not use this tag on your own questions. See the tag description for why. Please do help with adding this tag to others' questions when the issue has been confirmed to be a bug by the community.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have now coded both an importer and an exporter for the Sparse6 format, which I believe abide by the specs up to the special padding cases:

"1. If (n,k) = (2,1), (4,2), (8,3) or (16,4), and vertex n-2 has an edge but n-1 doesn't have an edge, and there are k+1 or more bits to pad, then pad with one 0-bit and enough 1-bits to complete the multiple of 6."

These do not appear in my problem, but it shouldn't be too hard to take them into account. How would I go about contributing this to the IGraph/M package?

Comment: I think indeed the padding is incorrect in Mathematica's implementation, and this can be a problem in nauty sometimes. I will try to pinpoint some cases where it leads to wrong results (I'm dealing with sets of a few million multigraphs without self-loops, and after Import / Export I kept seeing self-loops, but haven't actually done the filtering required to see where these appear)

Comment: On a sidenote, a different problem arises in Windows since Mathematica exports "Sparse6" as text, and thus uses \r\n for line endings where I believe the specs call for an end-of-line character \n, i.e. Unix line endings. This can be easily corrected, however, using `Export[filename, ExportString[graphs, "Sparse6"], "String"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132157/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-fidel-i-schaposnik).